# How do you invert a color by %?

Tags: css, graphics

I know to invert a color you do:

```
invertedColor = 255 - color
```

But say I want to invert the color by 75%. How do I calculate that? I am trying it like this:

```
original color is rgb(100, 100, 100)
255 - 100 = 155
155 * .75 = 116.25
therefore i think (incorrectly) that my new color should be ~rgb(116, 116, 116)
```

But if you look at this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/2gghvr5t/) the correct color is rgb(141, 141, 141);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inversion of color is actually (conceptually speaking, since 0% of anything is 0)

```
0% * color + 100% * (255 - color)
```

So a 75% inversion of color is

```
25% * color + 75% * (255 - color)
```

Basically you need some of the original color too.